# React setState happens after second click

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set data in **setSinglePostData()** from another data source but its showing
[image]

as you can see:

```
const [singlePostData, setSinglePostData] = useState([]);

<div>
{allPosts.map((post, index) => (
<h3
  style={{ marginLeft: 40, marginTop: -30 }}
  onClick={() => {
   setSinglePostData({
    ...post,
    index: index,
   });
   console.log(singlePostData);
   getPosts();
 }}
>
b\{post.user.name}
</h3>
))}
</div>
```

.map part

```
{singlePostData.map((post, index) => (
  <h2>{post.title}</h2>
))}
```

get all posts function

```
  const getPosts = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(postsControllerRef);
    setPosts(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    setLoading(false);
  };
```

Comment: When did you receive this error ? On initial loading  of the page ?

Comment: no after pressing this h3 tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects, `{}` in JavaScript do not have the method .map(). It's only for Arrays, `[]`.

So in order for your code to work change:

```
 onClick={() => {
   setSinglePostData({
    ...post,
    index: index,
   });
   console.log(singlePostData);
   getPosts();
 }}
>
```

to

```
 onClick={() => {
   setSinglePostData([
    ...post,
    index: index,
   ]);
   console.log(singlePostData);
   getPosts();
 }}
>
```

Because with your variant you are using `...` spread operator inside Object `{}` and  that change the state to Object instead of Array

Comment: I would either change to `setSinglePostData([ { ...post, index } ]);` or remove `{singlePostData.map((post, index) => ( ... })}` and replace it with `<h2>{singlePostData?.title}</h2>` (or something). Your code is not correct because `post` is not an array, but you are trying to do `[ ...post ]`